# How to reference group totals in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I have stores that are in various regions around the US, separated into counties called DMA_NAME. The weekly sales volume is also listed in the table/matrix as SWKLYVOL. When I view my data as a matrix, each county (DMA) has auto-calculated the Total SWKLYVOL.
What I want to do is reference this DMA group total in a new measure so that I can calculate each store's market share as a percentage of each county's Total SWKLYVOL.
Here is an image snip of the matrix as it stands now:
[click for image snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxj8g.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also I cannot seem to view your image but it may be just me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do exactly what you are asking (i.e., pull the subtotal value from the matrix visual). It looks like the closest you can get to what you are asking, using the visual, is to determine the percentage that each store's or county's SWKLYVOL is of the SWKLVOL column total or grand total. (For me, both options came out the same.)

To see what I'm talking about, select your matrix and then, in the fields section of Power BI, under values, drag in an extra SWKLYVOL field and click the dropdown arrow. Then click the arrow to the right of "Show value as." You'll see something like this:

[image]

You would then select the percentage type you want to use.

BUT... That won't give you what you are looking for.

Instead, you could calculate what you want using DAX. Maybe something like: `PercentOfCounty = Sheet1[SWKLYVOL]/calculate(sum(Sheet1[SWKLYVOL]),FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[DMA_NAME]=EARLIER(Sheet1[DMA_NAME])))`

[image]